# Enable hardware acceleration in Android app, targeting Honeycomb AND prior versions

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

To enable hardware acceleration in an Android 3.0+ app I can do this:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ... />
```

But the app won't build with that attribute present if I target an OS version pre-11. Is there a way to enable hardware acceleration in an app that targets both Honeycomb and prior, or is hardware acceleration only available for those creating apps that only work on 3.0+?

I had a look for a method on Activity but I don't see one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try to set build target to the 3.0 version, but set `minsdkversion` to the oldest version you want to support. It should at least allow you to build, but will not enable HW-acceleration on the older versions.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#hwaccel):

> Starting from Android 3.0, a hardware-accelerated OpenGL renderer is available to applications, to improve performance for many common 2D graphics operations. When the hardware-accelerated renderer is enabled, most operations in Canvas, Paint, Xfermode, ColorFilter, Shader, and Camera are accelerated. This results in smoother animations, smoother scrolling, and improved responsiveness overall, even for applications that do not explicitly make use the framework's OpenGL libraries.

Have not tested the 3.0 API yet myself, but the documentation seems to say this should be supported...

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
    <application ... >
    ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

(cut from [Optimizing Apps for Android 3.0](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html)

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately - I have minSdkVersion="5" and targetSdkVersion="11" but it will not build with the hardware acceleration attribute in the manifest. I'm hoping there's a way to do it at runtime, perhaps through a method I can call via reflection, though I cannot see one.

Comment: Installing 3.0 API myself now. Did you specify target version both places? manifest (as I just updated in my answer), as well as Eclipse project settings (if using Eclipse)?

Comment: I had the manifest set up with minSdkVersion="5" and targetSdkVersion"11" but you are of course right that the project also needed building against the platform 11 library. Thx.

Comment: change it in the project.properties file as well

Answer (score 9):

You can leave the min/targetSdkVersion as-is in your manifest. I have mine at 3 & 8. What you need to do is change the SDK you're compiling against. In Eclipse, go to Project Properties > Android and choose a Project API Target with an API Level of 11 or above (e.g., "Android 3.0").

Comment: this works. Just the compiling version should be above 11 and do a clean up of the project to solve the error