# Enable android:hardwareAccelerated, but build against a target earlier than 3.0

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to enable hardware acceleration for my android app, but I still want to build against Android 2.1 (in order to make sure I don't accidentally rely on APIs introduced in 3.0, for example). Is there anyway to turn on a feature and still build against a version before it was introduced? I know I can use reflection in code to check for say, an API added after my build target, but I'm not sure if I can do something similar for android:hardwareAccelerated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it's impossible to enable hardware acceleration while building pre-Honeycomb.

The main reason I wanted to build pre-Honeycomb was to ensure I don't use any API calls occuring after the minimally supported API level. I found that I can still get this by using the [API Analysis tool adt addon](https://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/) though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by setting your project properties in Eclipse to use the target SDK of API version 11 (3.0) so that you are compiling against a Honeycomb SDK, but then in your `AndroidManifest.xml` setting the max API version (`android:targetSdkVersion` to 7)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158824/enable-hardware-acceleration-in-android-app-targeting-honeycomb-and-prior-versio) for more info.

Comment: Your suggestion involves building against 3.0 (API level 11), which I wanted to avoid. It looks like I can still get the checking that I wanted by using the API Analysis tool at https://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I had in mind by suggesting setting the max API level, though to be honest I thought it was built into the ADT and not a separate plugin, so thanks for linking to the API Analysis plugin.