# disable Force GPU rendering programming

Tags: android, android-layout, gpu

I want disable Force GPU rendering in my android program . now i have to go setting on device and disable it , but it is hard for my user.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can turn it off by adding

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

If you trace the code into Window.setWindowManager(), you can see the following

```
public void setWindowManager(...) {
...
mHardwareAccelerated = hardwareAccelerated
                || SystemProperties.getBoolean(PROPERTY_HARDWARE_UI, false); 
...
}
```

Where,

hardwareAccelerated: comes from android:hardwareAccelerated

PROPERTY_HARDWARE_UI property is set by the "Force GPU rendering" option.

You can see that if user manually check the "Force GPU rendering" option, mHardwareAccelerated  variable will be assigned with a TRUE value no matter what android:hardwareAccelerated is.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning in Android 3.0 (API level 11),I think you can set

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

in the manifest file. Which will disable force gpu rendering for your application. Welcome and read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)..

Comment: thnx alot . but I have to run program in android 1.6 to up . but in android 3.0 & android 4.0 it have problem , and i have to change setting device that it i very bad

Comment: in API 4 i dont have this property "android:hardwareAccelerated="false""

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158824/enable-hardware-acceleration-in-android-app-targeting-honeycomb-and-prior-versi